# Macbook Pro 2017 (13", i5 256GB SSD) shows a folder with a question mark but works fine after recovery mode - until restarted again

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery

My Macbook Pro (2017, i5 256GB SSD) restarts to a black screen with a question mark within a folder.

Strangely enough, when I restart the computer and go into (forced) internet recovery mode, repairing within that, and then repairing (first aiding) in normal recovery mode (first step required to get into normal recovery mode), the computer works fine.

It seems this might have something to do with the battery - below 50% I only have to go into internet recovery mode once, then recovery mode once, while above 50% I have to do a lot more - once I had to restart into internet recovery mode four times.

Anyone else experiencing this? Thanks.

Comment: This happened  to me a few years ago and it turned out to be a swollen battery like in the duplicate question. I just bought a new Mac instead because it was easy to justify with my wife!